# Multiple File InBound Endpoint in the same flow

Tags: mule

I have two directories from where i want to pick files and send it to SFTP server , but i want to send directory1 files first , if it is successful then only i need to send files from directory2 . How do achieve this processing sequence  ?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Batch Processing documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing), you'll see an entry for [error handling](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing), which states the following (my emphasis):

> From time to time, when processing a batch job, a Mule message
> processor in a batch step may find itself unable to process a record.
> When this occurs – perhaps because of corrupted or incomplete record
> data – Mule has three options for handling a record-level error:
>
> - **stop processing the entire batch**, **skip any remaining batch steps** and push all records to the On Complete phase (where, ideally, you
>   have designed a report to notify you of failed records)
> - continue processing the batch regardless of any failed records, using filters to instruct subsequent batch steps how to handle failed
>   records
> - continue processing the batch regardless of any failed records (using filters to instruct subsequent batch steps how to handle failed
>   records), until the batch job accumulates a maximum number of failed
>   records at which point Mule pushes all records to the On Complete
>   phase (where, ideally, you have designed a report to notify you of
>   failed records)
>
> By default, Mule's batch jobs follow the first error handling option
> which halts processing as soon as Mule encounters a single
> record-level error.

So, to do what you require, you need to create a batch job where directory1 is processed first, then set `max-failed-records` to `0`.

Comment: Sequencing of files is also important . Batch Processing is asynchronous and it may post files from directory2 first , which i do not want . I want directory1 and then directory2.

Comment: No it won't because you would not run both batches concurrently. The idea being you run the _batch_ for directory1, and if it doesn't error, then run the batch for directory2 - I'm assuming that the order in which the files are sent is not important.

Answer (score 1):

1)Create 2 flows:- Flow1 and Flow2
 2)Configure both the flows with file inbound endpoint with 2 different folders .....
 3)Now suppose Flow1 need to execute first and flow 2 need to execute after that, make intial state property of flow 2 as stopped ..(So the file inbound endpoint of the flow will not pick the file from the directory) ......
 4)Put a flow reference in flow 1 after your execution happened so that it call flow 2 ... so it will happen sequentially 
example :-

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="f1">
<file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\folder1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
<!-- Do your busssiness proccess -->

 <!--Start the flow2 -->    
 <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
     <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('flow2').start()
     </scripting:script>
 </scripting:component>

  <!-- Now call the second flow using Flow ref -->
   <flow-ref name="flow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
  </flow>

 <flow name="flow2" doc:name="f2" initialState="stopped">
 <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\folder2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />

   <!-- Do your busssiness proccess -->
  </flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nicer solution I see is to use [Mule Module Requester](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester) to read the second set of files to later process them. Download the jar for Studio or Mule ESB standalone from the link and write a config like this:

```
<mule xmlns:mulerequester="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester" 
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" 
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester/current/mule-mulerequester.xsd">
    <file:connector name="File1" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:endpoint path="/temp/in2" name="File2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="main" doc:name="main">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/temp/in1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File1"/>
        <mulerequester:request resource="File2" returnClass=""/>
        <logger level="ERROR"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```